# How do you cite a GitHub issue or GitHub answers in paper

Tags: github, citations, conference, github-issues

I looked up on this subject but couldn't find an appropriate answer as to how should one cite a GitHub issue in a research paper's references section.
I wanted to cite [this issue](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1508) in the references. Could anyone tell the correct and complete way to do so ?

Thanks in advance!!